# How to remove header from iframe which redere a page of a different domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to render an iframe which contains a page from a different website but I don't want header of that site to be rendered. I found the solution for that but that works only when both the iframe and the page are on the same domain. Here both are from different domains. How to achieve this? Please help!